# hmvc in codeigniter cannot access modules

Tags: php, codeigniter

Iam trying to switch to hmvc in codeigniter. I will explain my issue from scratch itself. First I downloaded Codeignter 3.0 version from  http://www.codeigniter.com/download and when I check my browser it is showing the welcome message  of CI. Now to add hmvc structure I downloaded the hmvc modular extension from https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads. And placed the core and third party modules inside my CI folder. Then I created a Folder inside the application folder and named it as modules. Within modules I created a folder say test. I have a controller folder which contain test.php.

```
class Test extends MY_Controller {


public function index()
{
    echo "hey my first module is ready";
 }
}
```

But when i call the module in the url like localhost/index.php/test i got a page not found error. Am i missing any configuration? I got all other controller working well before i switched to hmvc. How can i fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you add the location for the "modules" folder in your config.php like described in the documentation of wiredesignz hmvc ? View my answer for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  to follow this tutorial.Here you will get ready to use HMVC folder. http://www.darwinbiler.com/ready-to-use-codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/

Comment: It is a link to an alternative HMVC Package, where the author talk a bit about wiredesignz's HMVC. It did not help here ....

Answer (score 4):

Do you forget this piece of code in your config file?

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);
```

Do you created your own Controller? Cause you extends `MY_Controller`.

If not, extend `CI_Controller` or `MX_Controller`

For more information read the documentation at [wiredesignz's HMVC for Codeigniter](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc%20%22wiredesignz%20HMVC%20for%20Codeigniter)

Kind regards